# runtime logger exception with dotty

Tags: scala, logging, runtimeexception, scala-macros, dotty

My project has a dependency on scala logging library and I am trying to upgrade my project to use dotty.
For that I cloned sample dotty project from https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-example-project and updated it include logging libraries. Please find below directory structure of project :-

```
[hduser@dotty dotty-example-project]$ tree
.
├── build.sbt
├── project
│   ├── build.properties
│   ├── plugins.sbt
│   └── project
└── src
    └── main
        └── scala
            └── Main.scala

5 directories, 4 files
```

project/build.properties :-

```
sbt.version=1.1.6
```

project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.lamp" % "sbt-dotty" % "0.2.2")
```

build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += ("com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.7.2").withDottyCompat(scalaVersion.value)

libraryDependencies += ("ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2").withDottyCompat(scalaVersion.value)

lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "dotty-example-project",
    description := "Example sbt project that compiles using Dotty",
    version := "0.1.0",

    scalaVersion := "0.9.0-RC1"
  )
```

src/main/scala/Main.scala

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging

object Main extends LazyLogging{

    def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
        logger.debug("Hello Dotty")
    }
}
```

above scala code compiles fine with

> sbt clean compile

But sbt run fails with below error :-

```
[info] Running Main
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger.debug(Ljava/lang/String;)V
[error] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger.debug(Ljava/lang/String;)V
[error]     at Main$.main(Main.scala:6)
[error]     at Main.main(Main.scala)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[error]     at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:93)
[error]     at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:87)
[error]     at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:65)
[error]     at sbt.Run.$anonfun$run$4(Run.scala:77)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]     at sbt.util.InterfaceUtil$$anon$1.get(InterfaceUtil.scala:10)
[error]     at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:252)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
[error]     at sbt.Run$.executeTrapExit(Run.scala:124)
[error]     at sbt.Run.run(Run.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunTask$5(Defaults.scala:1185)
[error]     at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunTask$5$adapted(Defaults.scala:1180)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool.$anonfun$run$1(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:366)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool$BackgroundRunnable.run(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:289)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Sep 1, 2018 6:02:01 AM
```

As suggested [here](https://gitter.im/lampepfl/dotty#utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=unread-notifications), it may be because of macros.

Kindly suggest, as my weekend project has a dependency on loggin, and i want to upgrade it to dotty.

Answer (score 2):

For now, the only thing you can do is find another logging dependency that does not require calling a macro to use it (or perhaps check the source code of scala-logging to see if there's an alternative way to call it that does not require macros)